# Javascript dynamic content event delegation problem

Tags: javascript, event-delegation

Every time when a button is clicked, a checkmark will be displayed. If the clicked button is not active, the checkmark is removed. Also when the button is clicked the "load dynamic content"-button will be displayed. There is a problem when dynamic content is loaded. After loading, checkmarks appear.But removing a checkmark does not work. I use a nested event listener for dynamic content. When I check console log after loading, button class elements has not changed. I cannot figure out how to solve this. Any advice?

```js
const checkMarks = document.querySelectorAll('.ck');
// Nested event delegation
document.querySelector('.parent').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.classList.contains('btn-link')){
    // Hide checkmark if not active button
    checkMarks.forEach(function(check, index){
      check.classList.remove('show');
    });
    // Display checkmark
    e.target.closest('div').querySelector('.ck').classList.add('show');
    // Display load dynamic button 
    document.querySelector('.load-content').classList.add('show');
  }
});

document.querySelector('.load-content').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.querySelector('.parent').innerHTML = '<div><button class="btn-link btn4">Button 4</button><span class="ck">checked</span></div><div><button class="btn-link btn5">Button 5</button><span class="ck">checked</span></div><div><button class="btn-link btn6">Button 6</button><span class="ck">checked</span></div>'
});
```

```css
.parent{
  padding: 30px;
}
.parent .footer{
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display: flex;
}
.btn-link{
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.load-content{
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
}
.load-content.show{
  display: block;
}
.ck{
  display: none;

}
.ck.show{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div><button class="btn-link btn1">Button 1</button><span class="ck">checked</span></div>
<div><button class="btn-link btn2">Button 2</button><span class="ck">checked</span></div>
<div><button class="btn-link btn3">Button 3</button><span class="ck">checked</span></div>
</div>
<div class="load"><button class="load-content">Load dynamic content</button></div><div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sisde/ex3jghon/16/)

Comment: Your title and tags already mention event delegation, but your code doesn't use that approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MDN: The Element method querySelectorAll() **returns a static (not live)** NodeList representing a list of elements matching the specified group of selectors.

So I changed that to getElementsByClassName, also the loop process, from forEach to for loop, here you go.

```js
const checkMarks = document.getElementsByClassName('ck'); // Changed that

// Nested event delegation
document.querySelector('.parent').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.classList.contains('btn-link')){
    // Hide checkmark if not active button
    for(let i = 0; i < checkMarks.length ; i++){ // Also that changed, as forEach doesn't work for getElementsByClassName.
      checkMarks[i].classList.remove('show');
    };
    // Display checkmark
    e.target.closest('div').querySelector('.ck').classList.add('show');
    // Display load dynamic button 
    document.querySelector('.load-content').classList.add('show');
  }
});

document.querySelector('.load-content').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.querySelector('.parent').innerHTML = '<div><button class="btn-link btn4">Button 4</button><span class="ck">checked</span></div><div><button class="btn-link btn5">Button 5</button><span class="ck">checked</span></div><div><button class="btn-link btn6">Button 6</button><span class="ck">checked</span></div>'
});
```

```css
.parent{
  padding: 30px;
}
.parent .footer{
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display: flex;
}
.btn-link{
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.load-content{
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
}
.load-content.show{
  display: block;
}
.ck{
  display: none;

}
.ck.show{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div><button class="btn-link btn1">Button 1</button><span class="ck">checked</span></div>
<div><button class="btn-link btn2">Button 2</button><span class="ck">checked</span></div>
<div><button class="btn-link btn3">Button 3</button><span class="ck">checked</span></div>
</div>
<div class="load"><button class="load-content">Load dynamic content</button></div><div>
```

Comment: Thank you for solution and clarifying method querySelectorAll(). I have to study more :)

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please vote it up. Thank you, have a good day.

Comment: I accepted your answer and vote it up.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The click handler on `.load-content` removes/replaces nodes present in your code and create new nodes. But these new nodes do not get picked up because this code:

`const checkMarks = document.querySelectorAll('.ck');`

Runs only one time and picks the checkmarks present at the page load. Try moving this expression inside `.parent` click handler to see if that helps.

---

Ideally you should be removing the click handler on `.parent` inside your `.load-content` click handler. Those handlers are still there and this presents memory leaks. You should be able to fix this by converting your anonymous click handler of `.parent` into a named function. Then you can simply use `removeEventListener` and `addEventListener` to remove and re-add the handlers.